# Pass Id to Controller from view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an html page which contains a list of employees

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${employees}">
<td></td>
<td th:text="${employee.id}" ></td>
<td th:text="${employee.first}" ></td>
<td th:text="${employee.last}" ></td>
<td th:text="${employee.email}" ></td>
<td><a href="/employee/${employee.id}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/employee/{id}", method= RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {

    try {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "DELTE FROM salesforce.Employee__c WHERE Id = '"+ id +"'";
        System.out.println(sql);
        int result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("execute update returned: " + result);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```

How can I pass the id so that I can delete the specific employee?

Thanks

Comment: you missed E in DELETE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your `Delete` link to look like this:

```
<a class="deleteLink" th:href="@{'/employee/' + ${employee.id}}">Delete</a>
```

And the controller needs a minor change too (check my comments in the code):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employee/{id}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
// "id" maybe not necessary but definitely a good practice
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    try {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;
        // not sure you need to put param in ' ' here
        // but you could try both varians and see if it makes any difference
        sql = "DELETE FROM salesforce.Employee__c WHERE Id = "+ id;
        System.out.println(sql);
        int result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("execute update returned: " + result);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```

I also changed the first line to `RequestMethod.GET` to make your link work on click.

But I don't think it is a right way. Instead of doing this - it is better to leave `RequestMethod.DELETE` there, but then you need a piece of javascript that will handle this link click and send DELETE method to the server.

I can provide an example with jQuery, but not sure you are using it! But just as an example of what I am trying to say:

```
$(".deleteLink").each(function (index) {
    let path = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour

        $.ajax({
            url: path ,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
                // Do something with the result
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code might need some fixes, I don't guarantee it works!

Hope this helps somehow.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have tried this but the error I get is o.s.web.servlet.pagenotfound request method 'get' not supported.

Comment: @Wearybands updated. check this line `@RequestMapping(value="/employee/{id}", method= RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: well i still dont get the id in url

Comment: http://localhost:8080/employee/$%7Bemployee.id%7D this is what I get when i click on delete

Comment: Try to open your debug console in your browser when you are on the page and find that `Delete` link and check how it looks like. You can also put HTML from debug console here

Comment: I checked it it looks like what I posted before

Comment: @Wearybands I updated my answer again. I made a minor typo. Please check again how `Delete` markup should look like. I guess this `<a class="deleteLink" th:href="@{/employee/{employee.id}}">Delete</a>` should work also, but not sure.

Comment: Sorry, updated again. Pretty sure this is the last update :)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the id in the correct way

```
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(“id”) int id) {...}
```

However, there is a problem with your sql query as you compare the given id as a string not as an integer. So try to use 
    “ ... where Id = “ + id

Comment: when I hover over the link the created url is not right it creates localhost:8080/employee/%employee.id%